# How can I save in a given cell the time and day I perform some task in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to know how it is possible to record the time and day I have done some task in Excel.

Example: I insert a number in cell `A2`, I would like Excel to show me at what time did I insert that number in cell `A2`.

```
Private Sub Time()
Dim r As Integer
Dim v As Integer

For r = 1 To 700

If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 2)) = True Then

   Cells(r, 1) = ""
   Else
   Cells(r, 1) = Time()

End If

Next
End Sub
```

This does not work, because whenever I write some new number in column 2 and execute the macro, VBA overwrites the previous times because of the For loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current approach, you have to manually run your macro to capture a time stamp (if you are manually running the macro, why not just manually use hotkeys to insert a time stamp?)

If you have to use VBA, this may be the better route to go.
The below code will execute automatically when a cell is physically changed (equation changes / formatting will not trigger the macro). Once triggered, the macro will build a `Range`/`Time Stamp` collection of every change made (restricted to sheet where this code is pasted) down column `Z`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim LRow As Long
        LRow = Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        Range("Z" & LRow) = Target.Address(False, False) & " changed at " & Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

Example output:

[image]